# How can non-developers manage static html files that are a part of an asp.net mvc core app?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wordpress, asp.net-core

I need a way to let non-developers manage partial html pages within an asp.net mvc core app so the developers aren't being bothered with simple content updates like text and image swaps - ideally using wordpress tools / plugins we already have (ie. divi or some other method) to manage those html partials.

Mainly I want to be able to control the layout (header, footer, nav) with asp.net core but load the content either within or external to the application for each page.

Ideally when we make changes to these partials, we don't even need to rebuild the app and deploy, we can just save / publish the files and move on, leaving the developers focused on their application jobs and the web updates can be handled by designers and project managers. I need suggestions on best practice workflow in this situation and tool recommendations - would I need something like a Joomla or Drupal or would Wordpress (ideally) be able to author partial pages that the asp.net core app can then link to and display?

We are using wordress plugins so non web developers can build and manage web sites and pages with little to no coding. We also have a few web developers who are programming applications needed by the org. These developers are getting requests that don't / shouldn't require a developer to complete, but some of these pages live within an older asp.net application we are updating.

Comment: *"I need suggestions on best practice workflow in this situation and tool recommendation"* - that's not appropriate on SO, take the [tour] and see [ask].

Comment: Sounds like you need a content management system (CMS). Take a look at Orchard Core, which can be used as a CMS and it can be used with ASP.NET Core. https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options

**Partial Views**

**The Views in ASP.NET are not compiled during deployment**. You can edit them on the production server **real-time without affecting any deployment process**. They are compiled real-time. All you have to do is press ctrl-F5 in your browser to get the latest views from the file system.

**Options for Workflow**

1. Refactor your content so that the partial views contain only content that is to be edited by the non-developers.

This would mean that the partial views that the non-developers edit contain only html and no razor-type code.

2. If you really don't want the non-developers touching the source code directory, including the views, you can have the content that they provide stored in a database.

This way in your controllers, you can check the database for the content the non-developer has stored, and save it in a ViewBag variable. That way the non-developers are not touching **any of the source code**

**Content Management**

If your non-developers are going to have access to source code files, why not just five them FTP access. Updating Views real-time is perfectly fine. Or you can look into using Subversion source code client to keep a version history